# making toast that use the java class .contains is not working

Tags: java, android

Im trying to make android app that shows a short toast about whether the link include the https or not and thats not working(no toast come up after the editing of the code) i think there are problems in the settings of class that uses '.contains()'... can i get help with these? those are written in java and tested in android 7.0 environment.

```
 package com.example.messengerandroid7;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.AlertDialog;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button button;
        TextView resultLabel;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        resultLabel = findViewById(R.id.resultLabel);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                class indexOf {
                    class contains {
                        public void main(String[] args) {
                            EditText url = findViewById(R.id.url);
                            String urlname = url.getText().toString();
                            Log.v(urlname, "test");
                            if (urlname.contains("https")) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "xxxxxx", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ㅇㅇㅇㅇㅇ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```